# How to Properly Delete a row of Control and dynamically create a new one in that position?

Tags: c++, mfc

My goal is to create a row of dynamic controls every time i click the `Add button` (on run-time), like this:

```
|             Combo box             |             |Add Button|

|Static Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Delete Button|
|Static Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Delete Button|(*)
|Static Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Edit Ctrl| |Delete Button|
```

and for example if i clicked on the `Delete Button(*)` , it will delete the whole row (including that `Delete button`). Then after that when click `Add` again, the newly created row will appeared at the same position, or even better if i could make all the rows below to move up, an the newly added row will appeared at the bottom.

Here are some code i wrote:

```
int CSettingDlg::Getid() // increase the id by 1 each time it was called
{
    id = id + 1; // int id = 4000 in the '.h' file
    return id;
}
```

```
int CSettingDlg::AddControlSet() // Add a row of control
{
    int index = 0;
    indexStr.Format(_T("%d"), index + 1);

    GetDlgItem(IDC_TEST1)->GetWindowRect(&rcCtrl);
    ScreenToClient(&rcCtrl);

    for (;;)
    {
        rcCtrl.top = rcCtrl.top + index * 35;
        rcCtrl.bottom = rcCtrl.bottom + index * 35;

        StaticText = new CStatic;
        EditBox = new CEdit;
        EditBox2 = new CEdit;
        EditBox3 = new CEdit;
        Delete = new CButton;

        StaticText->Create((indexStr), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY | SS_NOTIFY, CRect(rcCtrl.left -= 163, rcCtrl.top += 5, rcCtrl.right -= 270, rcCtrl.bottom), this, Getid());

        EditBox->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(rcCtrl.left += 28, rcCtrl.top -= 5, rcCtrl.right += 134, rcCtrl.bottom), this, Getid());

        EditBox2->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY, CRect(rcCtrl.left += 135, rcCtrl.top, rcCtrl.right += 136, rcCtrl.bottom), this, Getid());

        EditBox3->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(rcCtrl.left += 135, rcCtrl.top, rcCtrl.right += 172, rcCtrl.bottom), this, Getid());

        Delete->Create(_T("Del"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(rcCtrl.left += 191, rcCtrl.top, rcCtrl.right += 101, rcCtrl.bottom), this, Getid());

        index++;
        return TRUE;
        nCount++;
    }
}
```

And here is my basic idea to delete the row:

```
void CSettingDlg::OnBnClickedDeleteSettingDlg(UINT nID)
{
     nID == Getid();
     switch (nID)
     {
          case 3005: //3005 is the 1st Delete Button's ID
               for (; nID > 3000; nID--)
                    GetDlgItem(nID)->DestroyWindow(); //destroy all controls that have ID from 3001 to 3005
           nCount--; //This variable is not relevant
           break;

          case 3010: //The 2nd Delete Button's ID
          ...
}
```

I know my codes are pretty bad, so if anybody have a solution, hint to my question or at least know to make my code a little better i would be very appreciated.

Comment: You are conflating several different problems into this question. What you should do instead is to take a step back, analyze your issues, decompose them, and ask about those individual problems. That'll make for a lot more valuable questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vector to dynamically add/remove buttons. Note that each `new CWnd` pointer needs a corresponding `delete` to avoid resource leaks, so make sure to clean up when buttons are deleted. For simplicity you can put the controls for each row in a structure, as shown in the example below. You also have to reposition the controls when a row is added or deleted.

```
struct control_set
{
    CStatic st;
    CEdit e1, e2, e3;
    CButton bn;
};
std::vector<control_set*> vec;

CSettingDlg::~CSettingDlg()
{
    //for(auto &e : vec) delete e; <- remove this
}

void CSettingDlg::PostNcDestroy() // <- add this
{
    CDialog::PostNcDestroy();
    for(auto &e : vec)
        delete e;
    vec.clear();
}

void CSettingDlg::AddControlSet()
{
    vec.push_back(new control_set);
    vec.back()->st.Create(_T("text"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 0);
    vec.back()->e1.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 0);
    vec.back()->e2.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 0);
    vec.back()->e3.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 0);
    vec.back()->bn.Create(_T("del"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 0);
    resize_controls();
}

void CSettingDlg::OnBnClickedDeleteSettingDlg(UINT id)
{
    UINT row = id / 100;
    //add more checks to make sure this is the ID from delete buttons
    if(row < 0 || row >= vec.size()) return;
    delete vec[row];
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + row);
    resize_controls();
}

void CSettingDlg::resize_controls()
{
    CRect rc(10, 20, 10 + 50, 20 + 14);
    MapDialogRect(&rc);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<CWnd*> tmp{
          &vec[i]->st, &vec[i]->e1, &vec[i]->e2, &vec[i]->e3, &vec[i]->bn};
        CRect r = rc;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < tmp.size(); j++)
        {
            tmp[j]->MoveWindow(r);
            tmp[j]->SetDlgCtrlID(i * 100 + j);
            tmp[j]->SetFont(GetFont());
            r.OffsetRect(rc.Width() + 2, 0);
        }
        rc.OffsetRect(0, rc.Height() + 2);
    }
}
```

And you want to add message handler for delete buttons:

```
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(4, 904, OnBnClickedDeleteSettingDlg)
```

---

Alternatively you can set the position for the control as follows. First, put 5 dummy static controls in the dialog resource, with the following IDs:

```
| IDC_REF_STATIC | IDC_REF_EDIT1 | IDC_REF_EDIT2 | IDC_REF_EDIT3 | IDC_REF_BUTTON |
```

These controls can be hidden.

Then use the coordinates of these dummy controls to position the new controls. You can just offset the rectangle to go to the next row.

```
void CSettingDlg::resize_controls()
{
    CWnd *st = GetDlgItem(IDC_REF_STATIC);
    CWnd *e1 = GetDlgItem(IDC_REF_EDIT1);
    CWnd *e2 = GetDlgItem(IDC_REF_EDIT2);
    CWnd *e3 = GetDlgItem(IDC_REF_EDIT3);
    CWnd *bn = GetDlgItem(IDC_REF_BUTTON);
    ASSERT(st && e1 && e2 && e3 && bn);

    CRect r, rc;
    st->GetWindowRect(&rc);
    ScreenToClient(&rc);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        //reposition the static control
        st->GetWindowRect(&r);
        ScreenToClient(&r);
        r.MoveToY(rc.top);
        vec[i]->st.MoveWindow(r);

        //edit1
        e1->GetWindowRect(&r);
        ScreenToClient(&r);
        r.MoveToY(rc.top);
        vec[i]->e1.MoveWindow(r);

        //edit2
        e2->GetWindowRect(&r);
        ScreenToClient(&r);
        r.MoveToY(rc.top);
        vec[i]->e2.MoveWindow(r);

        //edit3
        e3->GetWindowRect(&r);
        ScreenToClient(&r);
        r.MoveToY(rc.top);
        vec[i]->e3.MoveWindow(r);

        //button
        bn->GetWindowRect(&r);
        ScreenToClient(&r);
        r.MoveToY(rc.top);
        vec[i]->bn.MoveWindow(r);

        //move rc down by one row
        rc.OffsetRect(0, rc.Height() + 2);

        //Set the font for each control
        //Also set id for each control, based on the row
        vec[i]->st.SetDlgCtrlID(i * 100 + 1);
        vec[i]->st.SetFont(GetFont());

        vec[i]->e1.SetDlgCtrlID(i * 100 + 2);
        vec[i]->e1.SetFont(GetFont());

        vec[i]->e2.SetDlgCtrlID(i * 100 + 3);
        vec[i]->e2.SetFont(GetFont());

        vec[i]->e3.SetDlgCtrlID(i * 100 + 4);
        vec[i]->e3.SetFont(GetFont());

        vec[i]->bn.SetDlgCtrlID(i * 100 + 5);
        vec[i]->bn.SetFont(GetFont());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , you're my savior, your examples above works perfectly. But i'm not familiar with ```vector```, so i guess i will do more research about it. And the thing is,  i want my controls to have different sizes, Somewhat similar to this: ```|1|  |   Edit Box 1   |  | _       Edit Box 2      _ |  |Edit Box 3|  |DELETE|```. Can you show me how to do it with the code above? Or some more tips would be great.

Comment: And later i want to show different text strings from a ```Combo Box``` to those ```e2``` ```Edit Boxes```. How should i do it effectively ?

Comment: I added a second method for setting the control to different sizes. To rename the dialog controls, use `vec[0].e2.SetWindowText(_T("e2"))`. Where `vec[0].e2` is in the first row. `vec[0].e2` is in the second row. Check `vec.size()` to make sure you don't go out of bound.

Comment: But now all of the ```e2``` are having the same text. My goal is to pass different ```items``` in the ```Combo Box``` to each of the ```e2```. I just tried to ```UpdateData()```, but nothing change.

Comment: If you have two rows, then try this: `vec[0].e2.SetWindowText("row1-e2"); vec[1].e2.SetWindowText("row2-e2");`

Comment: I have like 7-10 rows, depends on how many time i click the ```Add Buttons```. i tried to use this ```for (int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++) {vec[i]->e2.SetWindowTextW(EBStr);}``` but didnt work.

Comment: That should work fine. I don't know what's `EBStr`. Try `vec[i]->e2.SetWindowTextW(L"TEST");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194572/discussion-between-turtle-lover-and-barmak-shemirani).

Comment: I don't know. Edit this question and show exactly what you have done.

Comment: Edit: added cleanup in `PostNcDestroy` in case the dialog is being reused.

Comment: Yes now it worked perfectly with my ```SettingDlg```. I dont know how to thank you enough for this. But i still have some more issue with this in another dialog box. (which also have the ```AddControlSet``` function, but this time i put it in ```OnInitDialog()```). I will create another question. Hope you could see it and give me more knowledge.